# Should I remove db.create_all() when rerunning my code?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I code I always comment out the `db.create_all()` to prevent creating a database. Is it ok to add `db.create_all()` in my source code even though I have already created my tables?

Comment: `create_all()` will not attempt to recreate tables already present in the target database (quoted from docs). To get the initial state, `drop_all` needs to be called before `create_all`. So it looks like it is safe, but there may be other factors to consider, so I will leave this only as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: it can be opinion base question. Some may suggest to remove lines of code if you don't use it - to make code cleaner. But I would keep it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the database tables have already been created, calling db.create_all() again won't do any harm. So you do not have to comment it.